# How can I restart Magic 2015 from the beginning?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2015

I have started the game, and would like to experiment with other packs, but I don't know how or where to reset my profile (I don't mind, I'm not that far into the game)

I got the game through one of my friends and don't currently have Steam, however reinstalling the game keeps the same profile

Answer (score 1):

Going into `%appdata%` on Windows, followed by a temporary file named "steam" due to installation.

Go to steam - next there is a single file you open, then you open 255420 then remote and delete `<number>.profile`